# Google apps script AppendRow to the top

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

As I know

> appendRow(rowContents)
>   add values to the bottom of the spreadsheet
>   But how to add data from form in multiple rows in top of spreadsheet?

So if in form i have rows

> 1. first, surname, name
> 2. second, surname, name
> 3. third, surname, name

in sheet it must be placed as, and each time to the top

[image]

so if another time in form will be

> 4. fourth, surname, name
> 5. fifth, surname, name
> 6. six, surname, name

data will be added like

[image]

Now I using this code, but it append all data to the end and works only with one row, i think i must loop throught all rows in form but how to do that?

```
function getValuesFromForm(form){
  var firstName = form.firstName,
      lastName = form.lastName,
      order = form.order,
      sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([order,lastName,firstName]);
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There's no single function to do this, but it's not that difficult write one. Here's an example:

```js
function prependRow(sheet, rowData) {
  sheet.insertRowBefore(1).getRange(1, 1, 1, rowData.length).setValues([rowData]);
}
```

I would actually allow for an optional index, let's say we want to insert after the 2nd row, skipping the header.

```
function insertRow(sheet, rowData, optIndex) {
  var index = optIndex || 1;
  sheet.insertRowBefore(index).getRange(index, 1, 1, rowData.length).setValues([rowData]);
}
```

But `appendRow` also has another interesting characteristic, it's concurrent-safe. Which means it can be triggered multiple times in parallel and won't mess up. To make our function concurrent safe you have to `lock` it, like this:

```
function insertRow(sheet, rowData, optIndex) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);
  try { 
    var index = optIndex || 1;
    sheet.insertRowBefore(index).getRange(index, 1, 1, rowData.length).setValues([rowData]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  } finally {
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}
```

Then, to use it in your code just call..

```
function getValuesFromForm(form){
  //...
  insertRow(sheet, [order,lastName,firstName]); //could have passed an extra `2` parameter to skip a one line header
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this @HenriqueAbreu! I just need to add a row to the top so I am wanting to use the main part of your script above. But I don't see where to reference which sheet/tab I am dealing with in the script? Can you help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: @Drewdavid the proposed function takes the `sheet ` as the first parameter, just fetch it in your script, like you'd regularly (e.g. `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('whatever')`)

Comment: Be sure you convert the rowData passed to insertRow into a nested array or the function won't work:

function insertRow(sheet, rowData, optIndex) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);
  try { 
    var index = optIndex || 1;
    sheet.insertRowBefore(index).getRange(index, 1, 1, rowData.length).setValues(new Array(rowData));
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  } finally {
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I missed that. will fix the answer